# Read in a csv for a jsFiddle within a pre tag

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart visualization via a jsFiddle. I've input my data into some `pre` tags, however, I am not seeing anything when I try to display my visualization.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/9pom9mu3/

Answer (score 1):

There are a few small problems in how you're trying to access your data.

1. [`text()` is a function provided on D3 selections](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#text), rather than an attribute. Thus in order to extract the text value from your `<pre id='data_csv'>...</pre>`, you need to do `d3.select('#data_csv').text()`.
2. You're using `d3.csv.parse`, which takes as input a *string*, and therefore is synchronous. Thus you don't pass it a function as an argument, but can just take the return value.

   ```
   var data = d3.csv.parse(d3.select('#data_csv').text());
   ```
3. Your data is comma- and space-separated (i.e. `", "`), rather than just comma-separated (`","`). In addition, there were four spaces in front of each row. Try this instead:

   ```
   <pre id='data_csv'>Variable,Year,Country
   36,1996,Canada
   34,1996,Mexico
   38,1998,Canada
   32,1998,Mexico
   42,2002,Canada
   37,2002,Mexico
   </pre>
   ```

If you make these changes, `data` will look like this:

```
[{"Variable":"36","Year":"1996","Country":"Canada"},
 {"Variable":"34","Year":"1996","Country":"Mexico"},
 {"Variable":"38","Year":"1998","Country":"Canada"},
 {"Variable":"32","Year":"1998","Country":"Mexico"},
 {"Variable":"42","Year":"2002","Country":"Canada"},
 {"Variable":"37","Year":"2002","Country":"Mexico"}]
```

Note that there are still some issues with your fiddle that prevent your barchart from showing up. For example, there is no "Medal Count" or "Gender" data, which are used in a number of places.

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead and updated it, though it looks like I'm still running into some issues. Copying it into a file separately and checking it out with dev tools is showing that data.forEach is not a function -- though this is the way that I was accessing the data before I tried to read it in with the <pre> tag. Do you know why that appears to be an invalid function? http://jsfiddle.net/9pom9mu3/1/

Comment: @orange1: yes, it's because you are still passing `d3.csv.parse` a function, within which you try to do `data.forEach`. You don't need to pass `d3.csv.parse` a function, so remove it and call `data.forEach` in the main body of the script.